# CSS not loading in Chrome on Mac

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

Works on all other browser/OS combos I've tried.

This is the link: http://blumingcreativity.com/

Weird thing is that the CSS does get loaded on my test server here: http://pollak-labs.com/clients/tara/

I'm honestly at a loss to know what the difference is between the two. Code is pretty much identical but Chrome doesn't like the first link's CSS for some reason.

Comment: css is loading fine on my chrome / osx combo...

Comment: works for me... try to clear your cache

Comment: I got it working. I had to rename the CSS file and then my client reloaded on her machine. I guess Chrome has a very strong cache grip.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any plugins in chrome on mac? Try disabling them. `chrome://plugins`

Answer (score 1):

try cleaning the cache and reloading the page. Maybe Chrome "remembers" an old version of your css file.

```
chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
```

(I tested both links and they work fine on FF and Chrome)

Comment: It's actually happening on a client's machine. I waiting for her to clear her cache and report back to me.